# What does shasum's --portable option do?

Tags: shell, checksum

The `shasum` utility has a a `-p/--portable` option with the following description:

```
-p, --portable     read files in portable mode
                   produces same digest on Windows/Unix/Mac
```

I've never seen the inclusion this option change the digest of a file, and I'm not really sure what effect it's supposed to have either. What is this "portable mode" of reading files?

Comment: Takes in account different EOL characters?

Comment: @DavidPostill Maybe, though that'd be strange too. Different EOLs makes for different files, and thus they _should_ have different digests, right? The platforms's EOLs doesn't seem like something shasum should try to interpret/coerce

Comment: For what it's worth [shasum](http://perldoc.perl.org/shasum.html) says "   -p, --portable    read in portable mode (**to be deprecated**)

Comment: @DavidPostill Ah, didn't say that in my manpage for it. Only makes it more mysterious :)

Comment: Answer added ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What is this "portable mode" of reading files?

For what it's worth [shasum](http://perldoc.perl.org/shasum.html) says:

> -p, --portable    read in portable mode (**to be deprecated**)

As far as I can tell (I am no perl expert) it appears to be there to take into account different EOL characters.

The [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CPANInternal/CPANInternal-62/Digest-SHA/shasum.auto.html) says:

```
The sums are computed as described in FIPS PUB 180-2.  When checking, the
input should be a former output of this program.  The default mode is to
print a line with checksum, a character indicating type (`*' for binary,
`?' for portable, ` ' for text), and name for each FILE.
```

...

```
# Try to figure out if the OS is DOS-like.  If it is,
    # default to binary mode when reading files, unless
    # explicitly overriden by command line "--text" or
    # "--portable" options.
```

...

I'm happy for any perl experts to look at the complete source code and confirm my answer.

Comment: well, darn. Your hunch was right - still a strange feature, but alright. I'll wait a bit and see if anyone else has something to add, but I suspect the checkmark's yours